# PHP - How to get order from query and get "place number"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

How can I select the top 40 data from a table (based on `amount`) and then find where a specific user is placed in that data group?

Example, I select the top 40 data:

```
if($userdata['forum_moderator'] == 1){
$c = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM referral_competition ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 5");
$c->execute();

$competition = $c->fetchAll();

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($competition);
    echo "</pre>";
```

That gives me:

```
[0]=>
 array(2) {
    ["userid"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "14"
  }
[1]=>
 array(2) {
    ["userid"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
[2]=>
 array(2) {
    ["userid"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(2) "8"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "8"
  }
[3]=>
 array(2) {
    ["userid"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(2) "3"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "3"
  } 
etc. etc.
```

How can I find out where a specific user is placed in the array above, based on the users id?

Example:

You are placed `number 3`, and you have `amount: 8`

Comment: Why not simply use the array key of $competition and add 1?

Comment: What do you mean by "add 1"? Could you make an example?

Comment: The user with the userid of 4 is element of $competition[2], therefor she's placed number 2 + 1 = 3 ...

Comment: @VMai But how would I do that? Like: $comptitions[$userid]+1 ?

Comment: I don't know what you do with this array, so I can't say. The benefit of the solution of juergen d is that the rank is included in the array element and not dependent of the array itself. The part where you process this array is somehow missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner select get the top 40 and add a rank column to it. The other select gets only the specific user's rank and amount.

```
select amount, rank 
from 
(
  SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
  FROM referral_competition 
  CROSS JOIN (select @rank := 0) r
  ORDER BY amount DESC 
  LIMIT 40
) tmp
where userid = $someUser
```

Comment: Thanks, it now show the correct "order" when I do a var_dump(). Although, when I try to echo it out: <?php echo $competition["rank"]; ?> nothing is shown.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you there. This seems to be a PHP issue which I am not an expert of.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not require you to change the sql query you already have. It also gives you quick access to the user data.

```
  $ordered = [];
  foreach($competition as $k=>$result) {
    $rank = $k + 1; //Add plus one as the indexed resultset starts from zero
    $user_id = $result['userid']; //Grab the user id
    $ordered[$user_id]=$result; //Little trick to add the user id as the array index key
    $ordered[$user_id]['rank']=$rank; //Add the rank as new array element
  }

  //Now you can get any user record out of the array by using the userid as key

  //Example:
  $user = $ordered[3];
  $rank = $user['rank'];
```